# What is the name given to the practice/pattern of exposing properties of properties as immediate properties?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I believe there is a person who named this pattern or practice and would like to know the correct nomenclature to avoid confusion.

```
object.propertyA.propertyB
```

becomes

```
object.propertyB
```

Comment: The use of 'child' and 'parent' in the title suggests something to do with inheritance that isn't actually the case.

Comment: Thanks @SeanBurton - I've updated the title to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly referred as [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Here are a few guidelines (as per Wikipedia page):

- Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
- Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
- Only talk to your immediate friends.

Some more reading:
http://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter